# Oracle Having Sum

Tags: oracle, having

I'm having trouble getting this Having Sum to work.  I am not sure if having the Sum in the select statement works as I'm a novice at Oracle SQL.  I'm trying to find where the total amount due is greater than the customer's credit limit.

```
SELECT ARCUSTO.CUSTNO,
       ARCUSTO.COMPANY,
       ARCUSTO.ID,
       ARCUSTO.FAX_NUMBER,
       ARCUSTO.STATUS_ID,
       ARCUSTO.CREDIT_LIMIT,
       ARCUSTO.ADDR1,
       ARCUSTO.ADDR2,
       ARCUSTO.ADDR3,
       ARCUSTO.CITY,
       ARCUSTO.STATE,
       ARCUSTO.ZIP,
       ARCUSTO.COUNTRY,
       ARCUSTO.PHONE_NUMBER,
       SUM(V_1_30_SUM.LEFT_TO_APPLY, V_30_60_SUM.LEFT_TO_APPLY, V_60_90_SUM.LEFT_TO_APPLY, V_90_SUM.LEFT_TO_APPLY, V_CURRENT_SUM.LEFT_TO_APPLY) Due
FROM   ( ( ( (IQMS.ARCUSTO ARCUSTO
              LEFT OUTER JOIN IQMS.V_1_30_SUM V_1_30_SUM
              ON ARCUSTO.ID=V_1_30_SUM.ARCUSTO_ID)
            LEFT OUTER JOIN IQMS.V_30_60_SUM V_30_60_SUM
            ON ARCUSTO.ID=V_30_60_SUM.ARCUSTO_ID)
          LEFT OUTER JOIN IQMS.V_60_90_SUM V_60_90_SUM
          ON ARCUSTO.ID=V_60_90_SUM.ARCUSTO_ID)
         LEFT OUTER JOIN IQMS.V_90_SUM V_90_SUM
         ON ARCUSTO.ID=V_90_SUM.ARCUSTO_ID)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN IQMS.V_CURRENT_SUM V_CURRENT_SUM
       ON ARCUSTO.ID=V_CURRENT_SUM.ARCUSTO_ID
ORDER BY
       ARCUSTO.CUSTNO,
       ARCUSTO.ID,
       ARCUSTO.COMPANY
HAVING SUM(Due) > ARCUST.CREDIT_LIMIT
```

Comment: The parentheses in the `FROM` clause are useless.

Comment: If you post a simple, standalone example, you can easier get more precise answers, and you can see the problem yourself more easier. You need a GROUP BY criteria first, then you can use the HAVING operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `SUM` does not support multiple expressions.
- The clauses go in the order: `WITH ... SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... GROUP BY ... HAVING ... ORDER BY ...`.
- In order to use the `HAVING` clause you need a `GROUP BY` clause if there are non-aggregated columns.
- You cannot use column aliases defined in the `SELECT` clause in the `WHERE` or the `HAVING` clauses.

Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT A.*,
         COALESCE( ( SELECT SUM( LEFT_TO_APPLY ) FROM V_1_30_SUM WHERE A.ID = ARCUSTO_ID ), 0 )
           + COALESCE( ( SELECT SUM( LEFT_TO_APPLY ) FROM V_30_60_SUM   WHERE A.ID = ARCUSTO_ID ), 0 )
           + COALESCE( ( SELECT SUM( LEFT_TO_APPLY ) FROM V_60_90_SUM   WHERE A.ID = ARCUSTO_ID ), 0 )
           + COALESCE( ( SELECT SUM( LEFT_TO_APPLY ) FROM V_90_SUM      WHERE A.ID = ARCUSTO_ID ), 0 )
           + COALESCE( ( SELECT SUM( LEFT_TO_APPLY ) FROM V_CURRENT_SUM WHERE A.ID = ARCUSTO_ID ), 0 ) AS Due
  FROM   IQMS.ARCUSTO A
  ORDER BY
         A.CUSTNO,
         A.ID,
         A.COMPANY
)
WHERE Due > Credit_Limit;
```

Comment: Wow, this is a lot more complicated than I thought it would be.  I apologize that I forgot to post the error.
@Ditto I am getting an error "Invalid SQL Statement"
-MT0 I am getting an error "SQL Command not properly Ended"

Comment: Thank you so much!  Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You should post the exact error you're getting, I'm making an assumption without it ..

You need a `GROUP BY` in there ... and your `HAVING` cannot reference the column alias .. you need to re-state the full `SUM` ..
And `ORDER BY` comes last.

so your final pieces should look like this:

```
  GROUP BY ARCUSTO.CUSTNO,
         ARCUSTO.COMPANY,
         ARCUSTO.ID,
         ARCUSTO.FAX_NUMBER,
         ARCUSTO.STATUS_ID,
         ARCUSTO.CREDIT_LIMIT,
         ARCUSTO.ADDR1,
         ARCUSTO.ADDR2,
         ARCUSTO.ADDR3,
         ARCUSTO.CITY,
         ARCUSTO.STATE,
         ARCUSTO.ZIP,
         ARCUSTO.COUNTRY,
         ARCUSTO.PHONE_NUMBER,
  HAVING SUM(V_1_30_SUM.LEFT_TO_APPLY, V_30_60_SUM.LEFT_TO_APPLY, V_60_90_SUM.LEFT_TO_APPLY, V_90_SUM.LEFT_TO_APPLY, V_CURRENT_SUM.LEFT_TO_APPLY)
              > ARCUST.CREDIT_LIMIT
  ORDER BY
         ARCUSTO.CUSTNO,
         ARCUSTO.ID,
         ARCUSTO.COMPANY
```

Try that and see if it works any better, and if not, please post the full - exact error message